# Can $(this ) object be used to point to a function

Tags: jquery, function, this, onchange, function-parameter

I have a code something below:

```
    function showHideOptions() {
        $("#template1, #template2, #template3, #template4").css("display","none");
        $(this).css("display","block");
}
```

And I have four select dropdowns, At a particular time I want to select only one on the option of template selector.

```
    <select id="masterdropdown">
        <option>T1</option>
        <option>T2</option>
        <option>T3</option>
        <option>T4</option>
    </select> 


<select id="template1" onchange="return showHideOptions();">
        <option>Template1</option>
        <option>Template2</option>
        <option>Template3</option>
        <option>Template4</option>
    </select> 


<select id="template2"  onchange="return showHideOptions();">
        <option>Template1</option>
        <option>Template2</option>
        <option>Template3</option>
        <option>Template4</option>
    </select> 

<select id="template3" onchange="return showHideOptions();">
        <option>Template1</option>
        <option>Template2</option>
        <option>Template3</option>
        <option>Template4</option>
    </select> 


<select id="template4" onchange="return showHideOptions();">
        <option>Template1</option>
        <option>Template2</option>
        <option>Template3</option>
        <option>Template4</option>
    </select>
```

CSS:

```
#template1, #template2, #template3, #template4{display:none;}
```

Basically I have a top dropdown(masterdropdown), which is always Visible this is also a template selector, On select of its options I want to show a particular template drodown that corresponds to that selected option in masterdropdown. How can this be acheived in jquery. does `$(this)` not work in this case, being called from a function.

Comment: `hide()` and `show()` are your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a working **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/X5mWL/

JS

```
$(function(){
        $("#masterdropdown").change(function() {
            $("#template1, #template2, #template3, #template4").hide();
            $($("#masterdropdown").val()).show();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
 <select id="masterdropdown">
        <option value="#template1">T1</option>
        <option value="#template2">T2</option>
        <option value="#template3">T3</option>
        <option value="#template4">T4</option>
    </select> 


<select id="template1">
        <option>Template1</option>
        <option>Template2</option>
        <option>Template3</option>
        <option>Template4</option>
    </select> 


<select id="template2">
        <option>Template1</option>
        <option>Template2</option>
        <option>Template3</option>
        <option>Template4</option>
    </select> 

<select id="template3">
        <option>Template1</option>
        <option>Template2</option>
        <option>Template3</option>
        <option>Template4</option>
    </select> 


<select id="template4">
        <option>Template1</option>
        <option>Template2</option>
        <option>Template3</option>
        <option>Template4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: why are you using nowrap(body) for jquery., How does it change as compared to on Dom Ready

Comment: It was for making your previous function work, its no longer needed if you use my method.

Comment: btw how does this differ from onDomReady, and what is the difference in using $("document").ready(function() {
//stuff here
})

Can I use $(function() {})  only once in my page

And $(function() {
//stuff here
})

Comment: `$("document").ready(function() { //stuff here })` and `$(function() { //stuff here })` are same, you can use these multiple times and jQuery combines these. `onDomReady` is a jsfiddle thing which is same as `$(document).ready()`. `nowrap(body)` plainly prints JS in body.

Comment: But, I cant give my options the values like id's of subsequent dropdowns, Is it possible to get around this problem

Comment: Keep these IDs in another JSON like `{T1:"#template1"}`

Answer (score 1):

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#masterdropdown').showHideOptions().change();
        });

        $.fn.showHideOptions = function() {
         this.change(function() {
           $(".templateDropdowns").hide();
           $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
        return this;
        };

        </script>

        <select id="masterdropdown">
        <option value="template1">template1</option>
        <option value="template2">template2</option>
        <option value="template3">template3</option>
        </select>  
        <select id="template1" class="templateDropdowns">
         <option>ta</option>
         <option>tat</option>
        </select>
        <select id="template2" class="templateDropdowns">
        <option>ete</option>
        <option>eTee</option>
        </select>
        <select id="template3" class="templateDropdowns">
        <option>Te</option>
        <option>Tet</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach a change event handler to your master drop down.

In it, just check the select value, and show/hide the corrisponding dropdowns.

Something like this (a bit rusty on javascript)

> $("masterdropdown").change(function() {
>
> ```
> $("#template1, #template2, #template3, #template4").hide();
> var selText = $(this).search("option:selected").text();
> if(selText == 'T1') $("#template1").show();
> if(selText == 'T2') $("#template2").show();
> if(selText == 'T3') $("#template3").show();
> if(selText == 'T4') $("#template4").show();
> ```
>
> });